# Forbidden for Azure Storage Table with managed identity contributor access to Storage Account through Azure Powershell Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am creating an Azure Powershell Function and am trying to access Tables in a Storage Account for which I have given contributor access to the Azure Function managed Identity.

I am able to get the storage account using Get-AzStorageAccount and thus get the Context. However, all access to tables gives me forbidden error. I am not able to create tables either. I have tried using Get-AzStorageTable, Get-AzTableTable but no success.

```
    2022-12-20T12:52:04Z   [Error]   ERROR: Forbidden

Exception             : 
    Type               : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.StorageException
    RequestInformation : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RequestResult
    TargetSite         : 
        Name          : CreateTableIfNotExists
        DeclaringType : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Model.Contract.StorageTableManagement
        MemberType    : Method
        Module        : Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Storage.dll
    Message            : Forbidden
    Source             : Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Storage
    HResult            : -2146233088
```

I am also having issues adding Powershell modules using the requirements.psd1 file. I am usually getting a 503 error.

Please help.

**Edit 1**
I tried this with SAS token as well but this did not work.

**Edit 2**
I am adding the code with the Mananged Identity

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$storageCtx = $storageAccount.Context
Write-Host $storageCtx.Name
New-AzStorageTable -Name 'TestTable' -Context $storageCtx
```

The storage context name is correctly displayed but the next line to create the table fails.

Comment: You would need one of the following roles: [Storage Table Data Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-contributor) or [Storage Table Data Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-reader).

Comment: I added the Storage Table Data Contributor role but that didn't help.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: @GauravMantri : Thanks for your help. Turns out this was an issue with the network configuration in the Storage account.

Comment: Hi Puneet, was your storage account behind a vnet? what network changes you made for this to work?